# CameraSource(vision api) not detecting when phone is in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-orientation, vision

I have created an app to track the eyes using Vision api and its working fine when phone is portrait mode but when I tilde the phone to landscape position then the app pauses the camera and went to onMissing() method.

Please give me some suggestion so that the app can work in both layouts or it can sense the eyes from any phone rotations (0,90,180,270)

Code:

```
private void createCameraResources() {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    // create and setup the face detector
    mFaceDetector = new FaceDetector.Builder(context)
            .setProminentFaceOnly(true)
            .setTrackingEnabled(true) 
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE) 
            .build();

    mFaceDetector.setProcessor(new LargestFaceFocusingProcessor(mFaceDetector, new FaceTracker()));

    if (!mFaceDetector.isOperational()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "createCameraResources: detector NOT operational");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "createCameraResources: detector operational");
    }
    mCameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, mFaceDetector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            .setRequestedFps(30f)
            .build();
}



public class FaceTracker extends Tracker<Face> {

private static final float PROB_THRESHOLD = 0.7f;
private static final String TAG = FaceTracker.class.getSimpleName();
private boolean leftClosed;
private boolean rightClosed;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Detector.Detections<Face> detections, Face face) {
    if (leftClosed && face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability() > PROB_THRESHOLD) {
        leftClosed = false;
    } else if (!leftClosed &&  face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability() < PROB_THRESHOLD){
        leftClosed = true;
    }
    if (rightClosed && face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability() > PROB_THRESHOLD) {
        rightClosed = false;
    } else if (!rightClosed && face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability() < PROB_THRESHOLD) {
        rightClosed = true;
    }

    if (leftClosed && !rightClosed) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new LeftEyeClosedEvent());
    } else if (rightClosed && !leftClosed) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new RightEyeClosedEvent());
    } else if (!leftClosed && !rightClosed) {
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new NeutralFaceEvent());
    }
}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.eyetoggle">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Corresponding XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="20dp"
tools:context="com.android.eyetoggle.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emoticon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/emoji_neutral" />
</LinearLayout>


<View
    android:id="@+id/light"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/green"
    app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="75%" />

</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Comment: Mind to google for `android orientation`?

Comment: I have already googled for this issue but couldn't find anything. For hardware.Camera api there is a way to set the display orientation.

Comment: It's Android basics...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for an orientation change and do something like,

```
private void startIfReady() throws IOException {
    if (mStartRequested && mSurfaceAvailable) {
        mCameraSource.start(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
        if (mOverlay != null) {
            Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
            int min = Math.min(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
            int max = Math.max(size.getWidth(), size.getHeight());
            if (isPortraitMode()) {
                // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated by
                // 90 degrees
                mOverlay.setCameraInfo(min, max, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
            } else {
                mOverlay.setCameraInfo(max, min, mCameraSource.getCameraFacing());
            }
            mOverlay.clear();
        }
        mStartRequested = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    int width = 320;
    int height = 240;
    if (mCameraSource != null) {
        Size size = mCameraSource.getPreviewSize();
        if (size != null) {
            width = size.getWidth();
            height = size.getHeight();
        }
    }

    // Swap width and height sizes when in portrait, since it will be rotated 90 degrees
    if (isPortraitMode()) {
        int tmp = width;
        width = height;
        height = tmp;
    }

private boolean isPortraitMode() {
    int orientation = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        return false;
    }
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        return true;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "isPortraitMode returning false by default");
    return false;
}
```

This is from the official Android Vision [github page](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/ui/camera/CameraSourcePreview.java).

Comment: Thanks @Shanky.. will check this code/link and update the results here

Comment: as per above code we have to show the Camera preview and then only it will work for surface holder. But in my case the Camera preview is false, camera is running in background and through service activity its running continuously, hence in my code there is no surfaceView holder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in to CameraSourcePreview class file. This is the file with all preview conditions.

here is the snippet:

```
if (childHeight > layoutHeight) {
    childHeight = layoutHeight;
    childWidth = (int)(((float) layoutHeight / (float) height) * width);
}
```

So, if you remove or handle it correctly, your problem can be solved.